# Need to add boolean instead of filtering

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation that successfully filters records using the following fragment:

```
     { '$match': { 'creator.roles': 'manager' } }
```

Now i want not to filter those records, but rather add indicator boolean key that would show whether each object was created by manager:

```
          {
            $addFields: {
              createdByManager: {
                $cond: [{ '$match': { 'creator.roles': 'manager' } }, true, false ]
              }
            }
          }
```

But it gives me an error that $match is unknown.  Could anyone please advise the correct way?

Comment: In the question plz include the schema of your documents for more accurate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        createdByManager: {
            $cond: [ { $in: ["manager", "$creator.roles"] }, true, false ]
        }
    }
}
```

The reason yours wasn't working is because `$cond` is expecting an [expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions), but `$match` is an [aggregation pipeline stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#stages-db-collection-aggregate).